# AssertionError Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a view which limits results based on user authentication. For some reason, list slicing always results in AssertionError Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

```
class CustomGalleryDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()[:3]

        else:
            return Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()
```

Even when I try

```
return Gallery.objects.all()[:3],
```

With no further filtering, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: the queryset is being filtered after being returned from your `get_queryset` method...

Comment: Do you mean possibly in the template of the 3rd party app?

Comment: I am not a mind reader so I have no idea where the filtering is happening, but it is clear that must be the case from the error you're getting

Comment: I'm kind of at a loss here. If you have any suggestions on where to look, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: you need to supply more details for someone else to help... please post the entire code for your view class

Comment: OK, I updated the view class code

Comment: def get_queryset(self, request):
        limited_ids = Items.objects.order_by("-id").values_list("id", flat=True)[:3]
        qs = super().get_queryset(request).filter(id__in=limited_ids)
        return qs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `DetailView` class.

You can see here in the [Django docs for `DetailsView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) that after your `get_queryset` method is called the next method is `get_object` (found in the `SingleObjectMixin` class)

You can find the source of that method at: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/views/generic/detail.py#L21

You can see from that code that the queryset is filtered, most likely by `.filter(pk=pk)`

If you want to limit the possible object choices to only the first three rows you need to approach it differently, for example:

```
class CustomGalleryDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            qs = Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()
            valid_ids = qs.values_list('pk', flat=True)[:3]
            return Gallery.objects.filter(pk__in=valid_ids)

        else:
            return Gallery.objects.on_site().is_public()
```

Comment: This solved the error, but it's not limiting any results. I supposed that's a different story.

Comment: what do you mean it's not limiting any results? if user is not logged in the queryset is limited to first three items

Comment: user.is_authenticated() always returns true. When I am logged in or logged out it shows the same results. EDIT: I think it's something to do with caching. There's definitely nothing wrong with your answer though

Comment: that is indeed another question... you can rely on Django's `user.is_authenticated()` to tell the truth, so you need to investigate why you have an authenticated user when you are not expecting one